# TapGestureRecogniser not getting called when a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a view A that handles UITapGestureRecogniser. When it's on its own everything works great.

I have another View B that holds six of the View A objects. When I add View B to my ViewController the UITapGestureRecogniser stops working.

I have `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on all the views.

Can anyone spot why it's not working?

How can I check if the tapGestures are being activated upon touch?

Thanks

Note: The ViewController doesn't have any UIGestureRecognisers on it

---

SingleView

```
class QTSingleSelectionView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    fileprivate func initialize() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTapListener))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func onTapListener() {
        print("tap")
        _isSelected.toggle()
        setSelection(isSelected: _isSelected, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Multiple views

```
class QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector: UIView {

    var selectors: [QTSingleSelectionView] = []

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    fileprivate func initialize() {

        for selector in selectors {
           selector.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        selectors.removeAll()

        guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }

        let count = dataSource.numberOfAnswers(self)

        for index in 0..<count {
            let selector = QTSingleSelectionView()

            selector.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargin + heightOfSelector*CGFloat(index), width: frame.width, height: heightOfSelector)
            selector.text = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, textForAnswerAtIndex: index)
            selector.selected = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, isItemSelectedAtIndex: index)
            selector.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            addSubview(selector)
        }
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
lazy var multipleChoiceView: QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector = {
    let selector = QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector()
    selector.dataSource = self
    selector.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return selector
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.addSubview(multipleChoiceView)

}
```

Comment: could you show some code?

Comment: @AndréSlotta i added the code, thanks

Comment: So the problem was because of not calling the init(frame: CGRect) initializer instead of init() on views, but you objected my answer by 'i dont have a problem with the location of the views' , I also mentioned in my comments to check for your multiView if it receive's gestureRecognizer, but you down voted my answer !

Comment: I didnt understand your answer, there was no explanation.
And instead of explaining you changed it, and the change was wrong.
And i didnt down vote your answer, some one else did (I up voted it for you)

Comment: thanks for up voting, and happy your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code. The **problem** is in line:

```
let selector = QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector() //Wrong!
```

This line initializes the view with frame (0,0,0,0), that means it cannot receive any touch event, even if you could see it. 
The **solution** is giving the view a size to receive events:

```
let selector = QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This -
Instead of :

```
for index in 0..<count {
        let selector = QTSingleSelectionView()

        selector.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargin + heightOfSelector*CGFloat(index), width: frame.width, height: heightOfSelector)
        selector.text = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, textForAnswerAtIndex: index)
        selector.selected = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, isItemSelectedAtIndex: index)
        selector.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addSubview(selector)
    }
```

You should use :

```
for index in 0..<count {
    let aFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargin + heightOfSelector*CGFloat(index), width: frame.width, height: heightOfSelector)
    let selector = QTSingleSelectionView(frame: aFrame)

    selector.text = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, textForAnswerAtIndex: index)
    selector.selected = dataSource.mutipleChoiceQuestionSelector(self, isItemSelectedAtIndex: index)
    selector.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(selector)
}
```

This will call the appropriate initializer which is `init(frame: CGRect)` which has the `initializer()` inside it. But right now your code call's default `init()` function of the `UIView` which does not have your custom initialize.

Comment: How does this answer my question? i dont have a problem with the location of the views, i have a problem with the tapGesture.

Comment: I edit the answer, also added the bottom description, see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: No need to change initialiser, the initialzer function does get called.

Comment: I switched and no difference.

Comment: okay I see , for your test purposes, you can add a gestureRecongnizer to your QTMutipleChoiceQuestionSelector to see if that gets the events.